# Stacked column chart in asp.net c# MVC razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, charts

I am trying to create a stacked column chart in asp.net c#. I am using razor view. I have searched a lot to find a solution but all I get is a snippet of code. Since I am new to asp.net I have no idea in creating charts. I fetch chart values from the database. Any working examples to create stacked column chart in razor view will be very helpful to me. I don't want any paid chart libraries. I got a code to create barchart but i don't how to make it as a stacked chart. Also I am not sure about the chart values

```
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
        name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] {  "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well since you're an asp.net beginner, code snippets are a good way to learn. It would also make your question a better fit for SO if you had some code to show cause your question 1) isn't actually a question 2) shows no effort of trying to help yourself. if you don't get my point, please read [the "how to ask" page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); Here's already a tip though : [built-in charting controls in .NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series)

Comment: @Bartdude please help me with razor view solution

Comment: All the help you might need, at least for a start, can easilly be found on the Internet. I don't know antyhing myself about asp.net charting, but a quick search lead me to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456771(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using MVC and razor I supose your project is a web app.

In this case I highly recommend you to use HTML5 canvas for graphics. It's learning curve is a bit high, but is very powerful.

If you want to skip the math and programming difficulties you also could use one of the many existing graph libraries. Including one I wrote:

https://github.com/Bardobrave/Graph.js

Here some examples with bar graphics:

```
var barData = [[10, -20, 125, 230, -25, 245, 260, 20, 125, 125, 305, 110], [150, -50, 175, 280, -75, 295, 210, -70, 185, -20, 355, 160]];
var container = document.getElementById("graphContainer");
var myGraph = new BarGraph(container);
myGraph.draw({
    data: barData,
    colors: ["#0F0", "blue"],
    labelsX: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DIC"],
fontSize: "9px"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bardobrave/exqLtyme/

Comment: Thanks for your reply man. Your js is cool. I am also interested in learning HTML5 canvas for graphics. I searched for it and found chartjs.org site. But they dont have stacked column chart. Can you pls help me with a link.

Comment: A link to what, exactly? Something like this? http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/stacked-charts/

Comment: In your Graph.js how to set customed intervals for y axis.

Comment: You have to play with unitStepY attribute, read the documentation to check how graphs behave. They will place marks each unitStepY units if your data range for the axis is divisible by this amount of units, in other case it'll calculate it's own marks. Also, if you find any bug using it or find they lack any functionality feel free to ask for them in Github

Answer (score 0):

[High Charts for .NET](https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) has been my goto solution for charting like this, you can reference their library and natively generate the chart image based on your data.
They also have a JS library to dynamically generate the charts in your views if you'd prefer that route.